# Sonar branch plugin does not show anything

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, branch

I've installed the opensource branch plugin on sonarqube 7.0.0 (the 1.0.1 release): https://github.com/msanez/sonar-branch-community

I've configured a pipeline step in Jenkins for a multibranch pipeline:

```
stage('Sonar Analyse'){
    tools {
        jdk 'ORACLE-JDK8-x86_64'
    }
    steps {
        withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube Test') {
            dir('path') {
                sh 'mvn -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch.name=my-multi-branch' 
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

After a run I can see the new branch in sonarqube. I can switch between the master and my multi-branch. While the master contains info about vulnerabilities, coverage, tests, code smells etc I can't see anything for my new branch:

> We couldn't find any results matching selected criteria. Try to change
>   filters to get some results.

This is showing up when I click on my-multi-branch while all filters are reset. Am I missing some configuration in sonarqube/jenkins/maven? 
I've switched between short and long living branches but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "when" condition?
For example:

```
stage ('sonar-branch'){
    when {
        not {
            branch 'master'
        }
    }
    steps {
        sh 'mvn -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch=${env.BRANCH_NAME}'
    }
}
```

Take a look at this [link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/branches/overview/).